# Microsoft Teams doesn't seem to send bots requests to the server after an SSL certificate update

Tags: microsoft-teams

As stated in the title, after I updated my server certificate (it was expiring), my bots in Microsoft Teams stop sending requests to my server and always error with "Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request".  Before the certificate update, the bots worked fine.  Does anybody know how to fix this or how to even debug this?  What is even more puzzling is my custom tabs in Teams work just fine, they can reach my server and request the tab contents.  It's just the bots that are not reaching my server.

Comment: Have you reauthenticated the bots?  A cached Oauth token could be invalidated by a cert change.

Comment: How do you do that @ZachChilders?

Comment: Could you please share BotId and SDK version that you are using?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT, they are outgoing webhooks, so there are no BotId AFAIK.  And i'm not using any SDK, just the latest version of Teams client and the web version of Teams.

Answer (score 2):

On a hunch, I tested my ssl cert using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and it said my certificate is not trusted.  Then I used my personal phone to test my domain and it also said my certificate has expired.  It turns out that in my work network, IT has a proxy between my server/domain name and the internet and they are serving a cached certificate, which has expired.  When I access my server/domain name from within our network, I hit the server directly instead of going through IT's proxy, so I thought there was no problem with my server.  That was the reason why custom tabs work and the bots don't.  The custom tabs are visited in the Teams client using an iframe, which is loaded within our network.  The bots are connected from Microsoft's servers outside our network so they go through my IT's proxy and got an expired certificate.